# How to get the value of an UPDATE ... RETURNING query in postgreSQL in Doctrine DBAL

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, dbal

I'm trying to use this correct postgreSQL query working with Doctrine DBAL but so far I'm not succeeding, the query is:

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE id = ? RETURNING field AS fieldName;
```

The query works ok but trying to recover the value from the RETURNING clause I found no way to get this value from the query result in DBAL.

I tried *getLastInsertedId* with the *fieldName* value and the return value of the call itself but no luck. Anyone knows a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Frequently the price you pay for using DB abstraction layers is not having access to all features of the underlying database. It probably has some limited way to get a single generated key only.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that but I was asking because maybe there was something I missed and there's a way to retrieve that info.

Comment: Presumably you're using `executeUpdate()`. Try `executeQuery()` instead, as if it was a SELECT.

Comment: Yep, I use `executeUpdate()`, sorry I did not said that. But `executeQuery()` returns a `PDOStatement` object only containing the same query string I send. But thanks man!

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. I'm publishing it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after fighting a little and with the help of @daniel-v%c3%a9rit%c3%a9 I found the way to do that.

To retrieve the data after an update with returning in postgres you must execute the query like this:

```
$statement = $conn->executeQuery($sql, $params);
$statement->fetchAll();
```

This way with only one query you do the update and get the last value updated.